# how to sent the ANY operand mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a two tables users (IDN,RoP) and search_info (IDN, Location, Age)  (IDN - is a key column )
I need collect and count the rows from database which have a correct type(RoP) and correct information (Location and Age).

so php :

```
$location = $_POST['location'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$type=$_SESSION['type'];
```

so then I make mysql code...it is doesn't select raws but it is count them. I know that query is not used anymore, but I used it for educational purpose.

```
$search_result= mysql_query("
            SELECT COUNT(a.IDN)
            FROM users AS a LEFT JOIN info_search AS b 
                ON a.IDN = b.IDN  
            Where a.RoP='$s_type' AND b.Location = '$location' AND b.Age = '$age'
    ");
$search=mysql_fetch_array($search_result);
```

So as you can see the code is working but here the staff. I sent the location 1, 2 or 3 , otherwise 0. So if location == 0 I would like to grab from database rows regardless location (in other words - ANY location). Similar with age. is it possible  realize on MYSQL? How to change variable that MYSQL grab any location? 
AND the last question in code. I'm trying to select requirement data, but have problem to  output them. so how to print this out?

```
$search_result= mysql_query("
            SELECT COUNT(a.IDN), a.IDN, b.location, b.age
            FROM users AS a LEFT JOIN info_search AS b 
                ON a.IDN = b.IDN  
            Where a.RoP='$s_type' AND b.Location = '$location' AND b.Age = '$age'
    ");
i=0;
while ($search=mysql_fetch_array($search_result))
{
$ar_result[] = $search; // some how I get only first row not all of them
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

```
<?php
$location = (int) $_POST['location'];
$age = (int) $_POST['age'];
$type=$_SESSION['type'];
$and_where = array();
if( $age )
{
  $and_where [] = "b.Age = '{$age}'";
}
if( $location )
{
  $and_where [] = "b.Location = '{$location}'";
}

if( ! empty( $and_where ))
{
  $and_where = ' AND ' . implode( ' AND ', $and_where);
} else {
  $and_where = '';
}

$sql =  "SELECT COUNT(a.IDN) ".
        "FROM users AS a LEFT JOIN info_search AS b ".
        "ON a.IDN = b.IDN Where a.RoP='{$s_type}'" . $and_where;

?>
```

Second:

```
$search_result= mysql_query("
            SELECT COUNT(a.IDN) as cnt, a.IDN, b.location, b.age
            FROM users AS a LEFT JOIN info_search AS b 
                ON a.IDN = b.IDN  
            Where a.RoP='$s_type' AND b.Location = '$location' AND b.Age = '$age'
    ");
i=0;
while ($search=mysql_fetch_array($search_result))
{
    $ar_result[] = $search ['cnt']; // some how I get only first row not all of them
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: well it probably obvious variant, I just thought about if it any specific symbol or parameter for that... But any way thanks.

Comment: Well, but I do not understand why you need a CONDITION that is triggered in ANY CASE? It same like "WHERE ... AND true AND ..." :-)

Comment: well, It is for the search, so if I don't give location as a search parameter than I need to choose rows regardless to a location.

Comment: the second part still doesn't work , it count 2 rows in my table, that is corect but get data only from one of them, $i=1 instead of $i=2

Comment: `$ar_result = array();
while ($search=mysql_fetch_array($search_result))
{
    $ar_result[] = $search ['cnt']; 
} 
$count = count( $ar_result );`

Comment: actually I found why it is, I delete Count(a.IDN) and get two rows, so I do Count in deferent function